# Get pointer to value using reflection

Tags: go, reflection

I have a function that iterates through all fields of an interface passed as parameter. In order to achieve this is I am using reflection. The issue is that I do not know how to obtain the address of a non-pointer field. Here is an example:

```
type Z struct {
    Id int
}

type V struct {
    Id int
    F Z
}

type T struct {
    Id int
    F V
}
```

The above code represents my test structures. Now here is the actual function which traverses a specified structure and lists details about it:

```
func InspectStruct(o interface{}) {
     val := reflect.ValueOf(o)
     if val.Kind() == reflect.Interface && !val.IsNil() {
        elm := val.Elem()
        if elm.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && !elm.IsNil() && elm.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            val = elm
        }
     }
     if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        val = val.Elem()
     }

    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        valueField := val.Field(i)
        typeField := val.Type().Field(i)
        address := "not-addressable"

        if valueField.Kind() == reflect.Interface && !valueField.IsNil() {
            elm := valueField.Elem()
            if elm.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && !elm.IsNil() && elm.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
                valueField = elm
            }
        }
        if valueField.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            valueField = valueField.Elem()
        }
        if valueField.CanAddr() {
            address = fmt.Sprint(valueField.Addr().Pointer())
        }

        fmt.Printf("Field Name: %s,\t Field Value: %v,\t Address: %v\t, Field type: %v\t, Field kind: %v\n", typeField.Name, 
            valueField.Interface(), address, typeField.Type, valueField.Kind())

        if valueField.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
            InspectStruct(valueField.Interface())
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the actual test after structure instantiation/initialization:

```
t := new(T)
t.Id = 1
t.F = *new(V)
t.F.Id = 2
t.F.F = *new(Z)
t.F.F.Id = 3

InspectStruct(t)
```

And finally the output of InspectStruct call:

```
Field Name: Id,  Field Value: 1,     Address: 408125440 , Field type: int   , Field kind: int
Field Name: F,   Field Value: {2 {3}},   Address: 408125444 , Field type: main.V    , Field kind: struct
Field Name: Id,  Field Value: 2,     Address: not-addressable   , Field type: int   , Field kind: int
Field Name: F,   Field Value: {3},   Address: not-addressable   , Field type: main.Z    , Field kind: struct
Field Name: Id,  Field Value: 3,     Address: not-addressable   , Field type: int   , Field kind: int
```

As you can see I am using recursion, so if one of the fields is a struct kind then I call InspectStruct for it.
**My issue is that though all fields have been initialized for the entire structure "t" hierarchy, I am not able to get the address for any field located at a higher depth than "t". I would really appreciate any help.**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Passing `reflect.Value` instead of `interface{}` seems to fix the problem, however I don't know why `valueField.Interface()` doesn't work.

Working example : http://play.golang.org/p/nleA2YWMj8

```
func InspectStructV(val reflect.Value) {
    if val.Kind() == reflect.Interface && !val.IsNil() {
        elm := val.Elem()
        if elm.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && !elm.IsNil() && elm.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            val = elm
        }
    }
    if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        val = val.Elem()
    }

    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        valueField := val.Field(i)
        typeField := val.Type().Field(i)
        address := "not-addressable"

        if valueField.Kind() == reflect.Interface && !valueField.IsNil() {
            elm := valueField.Elem()
            if elm.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && !elm.IsNil() && elm.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
                valueField = elm
            }
        }

        if valueField.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            valueField = valueField.Elem()

        }
        if valueField.CanAddr() {
            address = fmt.Sprintf("0x%X", valueField.Addr().Pointer())
        }

        fmt.Printf("Field Name: %s,\t Field Value: %v,\t Address: %v\t, Field type: %v\t, Field kind: %v\n", typeField.Name,
            valueField.Interface(), address, typeField.Type, valueField.Kind())

        if valueField.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
            InspectStructV(valueField)
        }
    }
}

func InspectStruct(v interface{}) {
    InspectStructV(reflect.ValueOf(v))
}
```

Comment: I have fixed one error on this code. Replace second if valueField.Kind() == reflect.Ptr { to if valueField.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && !valueField.IsNil() { for save from panic when field is pointer and nil

Answer (score 12):

The reason `Interface()` doesn't work is because of the interface wrapper it returns. To give an idea of what's going on, let's look at what we're doing without reflection:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    F Foo
}

type Foo struct {
    i int
}

func ExtractField(ptr *MyStruct) interface{} {
    return ptr.F
}

func main() {
    ms := &MyStruct{Foo{5}}
    f := ExtractField(ms).(Foo) // extract value
    f.i = 19
    fmt.Println(f, ms.F)            // ???
    fmt.Println(&f == &ms.F)        // Not the same!
}
```

([Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/pg-sMGSSTp))

However, think about the `interface{}` this returns. What is it wrapping? The **value** of `ptr.F` -- that is, a **copy** of it. This is what `value.Interface` does, it returns you the `interface{}` wrapping the field. There is no longer any pointer metadata, it's completely detached from the original struct.

As you'll note, [passing a value directly](http://play.golang.org/p/QDClB_IrpH) to `reflect.ValueOf` will always return `false` for CanAddr for the "top tier" -- because that address is meaningless, since it would give you the address of the copy of the value, changing it wouldn't really mean anything. (Keep in mind that pointers are values too -- if you want the address of a pointer-valued field like `*Foo`, you're really looking for `**Foo`).

So, in our example above, if we were to naively pass in `reflect.ValueOf(ExtractField(ms))` we'd get the `ValueOf` `f`, which not only doesn't have the address you want -- it isn't even addressable according to reflect because it would **never** give a valid address as far as reflect is concerned (the only address it could give you is the address of the internal value copy in the `Value` struct).

So why does passing the `Value` down the rabbit hole work? Well, the only real way to say it is that `reflect.Value` maintains the necessary metadata when you use `Elem` and `Field`, while the `interface{}` cannot. So while the `reflect.Value` may look like:

```
// Disclaimer: not the real structure of a reflect.Value
type Value struct {
    fieldAddress uintptr
    value        Foo
}
```

All it can give you is this

```
// Again, an abstraction of the real interface wrapper 
// just for illustration purposes
type interface{} struct {
    value Foo
}
```

Comment: Thanks for complementing @OneOfOne answer. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I went down a reflect rabbit hole today, learned a lot from studying this code and LinearZoetrope's answer, thank you.  I came to a different conclusion though about your problem which led to perhaps a more straightforward solution:

1) You're passing in a pointer to a struct when you originally call the function, but...

2) When you recurse by calling 'InspectStruct(valueField.Interface())', rather than passing the embedded structure by pointer, you're passing it by value.

Since you're passing by value, go will create a temporary and won't let you take the address.  Instead, when you recurse, call valueField.Addr().Interface(), which will pass a pointer to the embedded struct.

```
    if valueField.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
-     InspectStruct(valueField.Interface())
+     InspectStruct(valueField.Addr().Interface())
    }
```

With this change, I get the output you are expecting:

```
Field Name: Id,  Field Value: 1,     Address: 842350527552  , Field type: int   , Field kind: int
Field Name: F,   Field Value: {2 {3}},   Address: 842350527560  , Field type: lib.V , Field kind: struct
Field Name: Id,  Field Value: 2,     Address: 842350527560  , Field type: int   , Field kind: int
Field Name: F,   Field Value: {3},   Address: 842350527568  , Field type: lib.Z , Field kind: struct
Field Name: Id,  Field Value: 3,     Address: 842350527568  , Field type: int   , Field kind: int
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer of @OneofOne is perfect, but it is better to add one additional check

```
if valueField.IsValid() {
        fmt.Printf("Field Name: %s, Field Value: %v, Address: %v, Field type: %v, Field kind: %v\n", typeField.Name,
            valueField.Interface(), address, typeField.Type, valueField.Kind())
    }
```

it is needed because sometimes you can ask for interface from a zero value struct. Ones it happens, it will panic.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the above solutions fail if the element is not addressable. I found this way:

```
iface := valueField.Interface()
ptr := reflect.NewAt(fieldVal.Type(), unsafe.Pointer(&iface))
```