# Test for nil values in nested stucts

Tags: pointers, go, struct

I have a deeply nested struct in go. These are constructed by a json unmarshaller.

Quite some fields in this struct are however 'omitifempty' so I end op with a struct that can have nills in various places.

Example (the real thing is even deeper nested, and big: 400 lines of structs):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    Foo string
    Bar *Bar
}

type Bar struct {
    Bar string
    Baz *Baz
}

type Baz struct {
    Baz string
}

func main() {
    f1 := Foo{Foo: "f1"}
    f2 := Foo{Foo: "f2", Bar: &Bar{Bar: "br2"}}
    f3 := Foo{Foo: "f3", Bar: &Bar{Bar: "br3", Baz: &Baz{Baz: "bz3"}}}

    fmt.Println(f3.Bar.Baz.Baz) //-> bz3
    fmt.Println(f2.Bar.Baz.Baz) //-> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
    fmt.Println(f1.Bar.Baz.Baz) //-> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference    
    //so far so good, but

    //is there a more generic way to do this kind of testing?
    if f2.Bar != nil && f2.Bar.Baz != nil {
        fmt.Println(f2.Bar.Baz.Baz)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("something nil")
    }
}
```

The question is if there is a more generic way to test if some node in the reference tree is nil? I need to get a lot of different items and it will be a pain to write all these if statements. 
Oh and speed is of concern.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One elegant way (in my opinion) of handling it is to add getters to structs that are used as pointers. This "technique" is also used by the generated Go code of [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial), and it allows natural chaining of method calls without having to worry about runtime panic due to `nil` pointers.

In your example the `Bar` and `Baz` structs are used as pointers, so arm them with getters. The focus is on adding methods with pointer receiver, and first it must be checked if the receiver is `nil`. If so, return the zero value of the result type. If not, proceed to return the field of the struct:

```
func (b *Bar) GetBaz() *Baz {
    if b == nil {
        return nil
    }
    return b.Baz
}

func (b *Baz) GetBaz() string {
    if b == nil {
        return ""
    }
    return b.Baz
}
```

The good thing about methods with pointer receivers is that you may call them with `nil` receivers. It does not cause a runtime panic until you try to refer to their fields, which we don't, that's why we first check if the receiver is `nil` (ultimately, receivers act as normal parameters–and it's never an error to pass `nil` as a pointer argument).

Having the above getters, use is simplified to this, and no runtime panic occurs in any of these examples:

```
fmt.Println(f3.Bar.GetBaz().GetBaz()) // naturally no panic
fmt.Println(f2.Bar.GetBaz().GetBaz()) // No panic
fmt.Println(f1.Bar.GetBaz().GetBaz()) // No panic

if baz := f2.Bar.GetBaz(); baz != nil {
    fmt.Println(baz.GetBaz())
} else {
    fmt.Println("something nil")
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3pDCZYGmDqT).

Comment: I swapped the accepted answer to this one because this is what I ended up using: a lot of accessor functions. I could improve by using your `self==nil` test though.

Comment: I've found implementation of this approach for codegen: [google/go-github/github/gen-accessors.go](https://github.com/google/go-github/blob/7a077bbd7313615d4f924f12b065913ee94e1d58/github/gen-accessors.go)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid '[`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)' (reflection, as a "generic" way to test fields of any `struct`, a bit as in "[Get pointer to value using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24348184/6309)" or in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hvoecking/10772475#file-translate-go-L191-L204): it is slower), the surest way would be to implement methods on `Foo` in order to return the right value

```
func (foo *Foo) BarBaz() string {
    if f2.Bar != nil && f2.Bar.Baz != nil {
        return f2.Bar.Baz.Baz
    } else {
        fmt.Println("something nil")
        return "" // for example
    } 
}
```

If there are *a lot* of such functions to write, maybe [go 1.4 `go generate`](http://blog.golang.org/generate) command can help generate most of them.

Comment: Mmm, reflect is nice and generic, but to slow to be of use. I missed the go generate, and it looks interesting. Will dive into.

Comment: @RickyA yes, each time you see: " it will be a pain to write all these ... `<code>`", you now have the go 1.4 option of `go generate`: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Generate_Go_files_by_processing_source

Answer (score 0):

I've used `recover`:

```
package navigate

func recoverFrom(err any, panicPred func(e error) bool) {
    if err != nil {
        e, ok := err.(error)
        if !ok || panicPred(e) {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}

func RecoverFromNilPointerDereference() {
    recoverFrom(
        recover(),
        func(e error) bool {
            // unfortunately, there's no memory access object that can be matched, so we're forced to match by string
            // if this internal string changes, this function will need to be changed to match the new value
            const internalMemoryAccessErrorMsg = "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

            return e.Error() != internalMemoryAccessErrorMsg
        },
    )
}

func Safely[T any](navigate func() T) T {
    defer RecoverFromNilPointerDereference()

    return navigate()
}
```

Usage:

```
navigate.Safely(func() *string {
    return a.b.c
})
```