# How to check value in nested pointer

Tags: pointers, go, nested, panic

How can I check nested pointer easily?

```
type inner1 struct {
    value string
}

type inner2 struct {
    value *inner1
}

type outter struct {
    value *inner2
}
```

I have data like this:

```
o := &outter{
    value: &inner2{
        value: &inner1{
            value: "I need this data",
        },
    },
}
```

If I want to get data from this, I need to check for nil pointer.

```
func printValue(o *outter) (string, bool) {
    if o.value != nil {
        v1 := o.value
        if v1.value != nil {
            v2 := v1.value
            return v2.value, true
        }
    }
    return "", false
}
```

Yea, I can do this. But in my real scenario, this nested pointer part is much longer. I will prefer another way.

I have checked this answer, [Test for nil values in golang nested stucts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28215031/1924666). But I need alternative.

How can I accomplish this. Any efficient and better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panic and recover is for exceptional cases. Checking if a pointer is `nil` is usually not, so you should stay away from it. Checking if a pointer is `nil` using an `if` statement is much cleaner than to introduce a deferred function with `recover()`. Especially as this `recover()` will stop all other kinds of panic, even those that would result from other reasons than trying to dereference a `nil` pointer. (Using `defer` and `recover()` is also slower than a simple `nil` check using `if`.)

If the data is always required to be a non-`nil` value, you should consider not using a pointer for it. And if the data is always required to be non-`nil` but for some reason you are required to use a pointer, then this may be a valid case to let your code panic if any of the pointers are still `nil`.

If it may be `nil`, then you have to check the `nil` case and handle it appropriately. You have to be explicit about this, Go doesn't help you omit this check.

To avoid having to check `nil` in every place, a utility function or method is reasonable. Note that methods can be called even if the receiver is `nil` which may be useful in such cases.

For example you may attach the following methods:

```
func (i *inner1) Get() (string, bool) {
    if i == nil {
        return "", false
    }
    return i.value, true
}

func (i *inner2) Get() (string, bool) {
    if i == nil {
        return "", false
    }
    return i.value.Get()
}

func (o *outter) Get() (string, bool) {
    if o == nil {
        return "", false
    }
    return o.value.Get()
}
```

Note that each `Get()` method requires to check a single pointer, doesn't matter how complex the data structure is.

Testing it:

```
o := &outter{
    value: &inner2{
        value: &inner1{
            value: "I need this data",
        },
    },
}
fmt.Println(o.Get())

o.value.value = nil
fmt.Println(o.Get())

o.value = nil
fmt.Println(o.Get())

o = nil
fmt.Println(o.Get())
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WBPluYw0eZY)):

```
I need this data true
 false
 false
 false
```

The above solution *hides* the internals of `outter` which is useful for those using `outter` (doesn't need updating the clients if internals of `outter` change, just the `outter.Get()` method).

A similar approach would be to add methods that only return the field of the receiver struct:

```
func (i *inner1) Value() (string, bool) {
    if i == nil {
        return "", false
    }
    return i.value, true
}

func (i *inner2) Inner1() *inner1 {
    if i == nil {
        return nil
    }
    return i.value
}

func (o *outter) Inner2() *inner2 {
    if o == nil {
        return nil
    }
    return o.value
}
```

This approach requires clients to know internals of `outter`, but similarly it does not require any `nil` checks when using it:

```
o := &outter{
    value: &inner2{
        value: &inner1{
            value: "I need this data",
        },
    },
}
fmt.Println(o.Inner2().Inner1().Value())

o.value.value = nil
fmt.Println(o.Inner2().Inner1().Value())

o.value = nil
fmt.Println(o.Inner2().Inner1().Value())

o = nil
fmt.Println(o.Inner2().Inner1().Value())
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zRwKt_8wFOp).

Comment: @aerokite Check the addition about the example methods. Each method requires a single `nil` check regardless of the complexity of the data structure.

Comment: Seems like there is no easy way. Need redundant code for this checking purpose.

Comment: @aerokite You have to check for `nil` for each pointer at least _once_, _somewhere_. _That_ you cannot omit. All you have to decide is where to put this check. My examples contain `nil` pointer checks for each pointer only once. So there is no redundancy in that.

Comment: I did the same thing in my question, right? Logically

Comment: Thank you @icza for your valuable time. Its helps

Answer (score 0):

I can use panic recovery method. This will solve my problem. But this seems hacky to me.

```
func printValue(o *outter) (string, bool) {
    defer func() (string, bool) {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            return "", false
        }
        return "", false
    }()
    return o.value.value.value, true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way. You may go recover way but it's not idiomatic IMO and you should check that you don't catch other unrelated errors.

I prefer a single `if` instead of multiple. I don't think of the code below ugly or verbose.

```
func printValue(o *outter) (string, bool) {
    if o.value != nil and o.value.value != nil and o.value.value.value != nil {
        return *o.value.value.value, true
    }
    return "", false
}
```

Comment: You are right. But if nested length is 10, I need lots of checking. I was looking for alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection

```
func getFieldByName(v interface{}, fields string, sep string) interface{} {
    r := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    s := strings.Split(fields, sep)
    for _, field := range s {
        r = reflect.Indirect(r)
        if r.IsValid() {
            r = reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName(field)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    if r.IsValid() {
        return r.Interface()
    }
    return nil
}
```

Using Panic Recovery

```
type safeGetFn func() interface{}

func safeGet(f safeGetFn, d interface{}) (ret interface{}) {
    defer func() interface{} {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            ret = d
        }
        return ret
    }()
    return f()
}
```

Example Reflection: https://play.golang.org/p/m0_zQqJm7MY

Example Panic Recovery: https://play.golang.org/p/PNPPBXCvHxJ