# How does Go bind methods to Objects?

Tags: go, pointers, methods, binding

I just started learning Go a few days ago.Today, we were debugging a piece of code for a while when we found something that seem counterintuitive of Go to do.

First we defined an interface and a data structure that implements it.

```golang
type Executer interface {
    Execute()
}

type whatever struct {
    name string
}

func (this *whatever) Execute() {
    log.Println(this.name)
}
```

Now consider that I have a nil pointer to `whatever` and I try to call the method `Execute`. In other object-oriented languages I have used so far, this would call a null pointer error at the point of calling the method (i.e. `w.Execute()`) since the object pointer is null. Interestingly, in Go, the method is invoked, the null pointer error occurs at the `Execute` method when I try to dereference `this.name`. Why not at the point of calling the method?

```golang
func main() {
    var w *whatever
    w.Execute()
}
```

So, what I'm seeking to understand now is how is this possible? Does this mean that Go only does early method binding at compile time and at runtime there is no binding of the method with a specific object?

Comment: The receiver is just an "ordinary" argument to the function. If it's a pointer, it may be `nil`. In Java you can call static methods on `null` objects too.

Comment: Here's a use case for `nil` receivers: [Test for nil values in nested stucts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215031/test-for-nil-values-in-nested-stucts/58100426#58100426)

Comment: @icza Interesting! I hadn't considered that angle. Although, when a method is static in Java, I can follow a better pattern when calling it by doing `T.method()` where `T` is a type, instead `obj.method()` where `obj` is an object. It appears I cannot do that in Go, because the interface is lifeless without binding it to a specific `struct`. The style of invocation confused me and made me believe that the instance of `struct` was the target, it appears it is the `struct` type that binds it.

Comment: Yes, because Go is simpler: there are no static, public, protected, private, package private etc. modifiers. In Go there is only exported and non-exported. But Go has some sweetness too: method expressions and values. See [golang function alias on method receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251283/golang-function-alias-on-method-receiver/28252088#28252088); and [Pass method argument to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897529/pass-method-argument-to-function/38897667#38897667).

Comment: @velkor Understood. And all that binding is done at compile time, right? Now that it has been clarified that methods behave in a similar way to static methods in other languages like Java or C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The receiver is just an "ordinary" argument to the function. Ordinary parameters may be of pointer types. When then are, you are allowed to pass `nil` as the argument, which is perfectly valid. All you need to keep in mind is not to dereference `nil` pointer arguments. The same applies to the special receiver parameter too. If it's a pointer, it may be `nil`, you just must not dereference it.

[Spec: Method declarations:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations)

> The receiver is specified via an extra parameter section preceding the method name.
>
> ... The method is said to be *bound* to its receiver base type and the method name is visible only within [selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) for type `T` or `*T`.

Allowing `nil` receiver values is not just something not forbidden, it has practical uses. For an example, see [Test for nil values in nested stucts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215031/test-for-nil-values-in-nested-stucts/58100426#58100426).

In Java you can call static methods on `null` objects too. It's true you can't do the same in Go, because Go does not have modifiers like `static`, `public`, `private` etc. In Go there are only exported and non-exported methods (implied by the first latter of their name).

But Go offers something similar too: [Method expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions) and [Method values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values). If you have a method `m` with `T` receiver type, the expression `T.m` will be a function value whose signature contains the parameters and result types of `m` "prefixed" with the receiver type.

For example:

```
type Foo int

func (f Foo) Bar(s string) string { return fmt.Sprint(s, f) }

func main() {
    fooBar := Foo.Bar // A function of type: func(Foo, string) string
    res := fooBar(1, "Go")
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

`Foo.Bar` will be a function with type `func (Foo, string) string`, and you can call it like any other ordinary function; and you also have to pass the receiver as the first argument. The above app outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ImU914D7P-v)):

```
Go1
```

Going a little "forward", we are not required to store `Foo.Bar` in a variable, we can directly call `Foo.Bar`:

```
fmt.Println(Foo.Bar(1, "Go"))
```

Which outputs the same (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rFmz8ZlTsvI)). Now this almost looks like a `static` method call in Java.

And as the "final" step, when we use the above expression on a value of `Foo` itself (instead of the type identifier), we arrive at the method values, which saves the receiver and so the type of a method value does not include the receiver, its signature will be that of the method, and we can call it without having to pass a receiver:

```
var f Foo = Foo(1)
bar := f.Bar
fmt.Println(bar("Go"))
```

This again will output the same, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3GBPT4mLO5Q).

See related questions:

[Pass method argument to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897529/pass-method-argument-to-function/38897667#38897667)

[golang function alias on method receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251283/golang-function-alias-on-method-receiver/28252088#28252088)