# Assign values from struct after checking nil

Tags: go

I have a struct that has elements which are a struct and so on.

Let's say I'm assigning as below:

`validFrom := dkdm.AuthenticatedPublic.RequiredExtensions.KDMRequiredExtensions.ContentKeysNotValidBefore` 
This data is dynamic and any element at anytime, can be nil due to parsing error or no data.

For example, `KDMRequiredExtensions` can be nil and when I try to access `ContentKeysNotValidBefore`, It will throw a nil pointer reference error.

Is it possible to have a method that takes in the element and check the value chain one by one and return only if no element is nil.

```golang
validFrom := checkAndAssign(dkdm.AuthenticatedPublic.RequiredExtensions.KDMRequiredExtensions.ContentKeysNotValidBefore)
```

I tried if statements before the assignment but would like to have a cleaner way.

```golang
if dkdm.AuthenticatedPublic.RequiredExtensions != nil &&
    dkdm.AuthenticatedPublic.RequiredExtensions.KDMRequiredExtension != nil {
      validFrom = dkdm.AuthenticatedPublic.RequiredExtensions.KDMRequiredExtensions.ContentKeysNotValidBefore
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test for nil values in nested stucts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215031/test-for-nil-values-in-nested-stucts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a method that takes in the element and check the value chain one by one and return only if no element is nil.

No, there is no such syntax or tooling in Go.

> I tried if statements before the assignment but would like to have a cleaner way.

The `if` statement *is* the "clean" way. You can shorten it a bit by introducing a new variable like

```
if re := dkdm.AuthenticatedPublic.RequiredExtensions; re != nil && 
    re.KDMRequiredExtension != nil  {
    ....
}
```