# Convert uintptr from reflection into pointer (*)

Tags: pointers, go

I just can't find the way to get a slice of pointer to each attribute of a given struct. I am using reflection to get my pointers (Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24348352/6093604)

```
if valueField.CanAddr() {
    address = fmt.Sprintf("0x%X", valueField.Addr().Pointer())
}
```

As you can see, valueField.Addr().Pointer() returns a pointer addr value, however, using reflection, I would like to get a usable pointer for `sql.Rows.Scan()`

So what did I do is:

```
func StructAttributesToPointersSlice(object interface{}) []interface{} {

    val := reflect.ValueOf(object)

    if val.Kind() == reflect.Interface && !val.IsNil() {
        elm := val.Elem()
        if elm.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && !elm.IsNil() && elm.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            val = elm
        }
    }
    if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        val = val.Elem()
    }

    var ptrs []interface{}
    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        valueField := val.Field(i)

        if valueField.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            valueField = valueField.Elem()

        }
        if valueField.CanAddr() {
            ptrs = append(ptrs, valueField.Addr().Pointer())
        }
    }

    return ptrs
}
```

But when I try to use it for `Scan()` sql function:

```
var values []interface{}

// Iterate over each rows got from the query
for rows.Next() {

    ptrs := utils.StructAttributesToPointersSlice(&newObject)

    for _, item := range ptrs {
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(item))
    }

    err = rows.Scan(ptrs...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, model.Status{Code: http.StatusInternalServerError, Error: err.Error()}
    } else {
        values = append(values, newObject)
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> sql: Scan error on column index 0: destination not a pointer

I know it's because it's not the good type since it's a `uintptr`, but then how to transform it into usable pointer?

Thanks

Comment: Addr() already returns a pointer value. Calling Pointer() on it is wrong. Probably you should extract the actual pointer via Interface() instead of Pointer().

Answer (score 1):

Use [unsafe.Pointer](http://godoc.org/unsafe#Pointer) to convert a uintptr to a pointer of some type. As an example, the following expression converts uintptr `u` to a `T` pointer:

```
(*T)(unsafe.Pointer(u))
```

This conversion does not help in `StructAttributesToPointersSlice` because the struct fields can be of any type.  Also, the conversion from `uintptr` is not needed and unsafe.

The expression `valueField.Addr()` is the reflect.Value for the pointer to the field. Call `Interface()` to get the actual pointer. To fix the program, change

```
ptrs = append(ptrs, valueField.Addr().Pointer())
```

to

```
ptrs = append(ptrs, valueField.Addr().Interface())
```

Here's a simplified version of the function:

```
func StructAttributesToPointersSlice(object interface{}) []interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(object)
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Ptr || v.Elem().Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        panic("argument must be a pointer to struct")
    }

    v = v.Elem()
    var result []interface{}
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        f := v.Field(i)
        if !f.CanSet() {
            continue
        }
        result = append(result, f.Addr().Interface())

    }
    return result
}
```

Some notes about this code:

- The argument must be a pointer to a struct.
- There's no need to call CanAddr on the fields. The check for pointer to struct covers this.
- The CanSet() skips over unexported fields. You may want it to panic instead.
- The function panics for errors in the caller. Consider returning an error instead.

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/kKNd_giJs2)